# Какой плагин jQuery Autocomplete лучше использовать

Tags: javascript, autocomplete

Есть очень большой json (12mb), что лучше использовать?

Это я написал на [Bassjobsen/typeahead](https://github.com/bassjobsen/Bootstrap-3-Typeahead/)

```
var $input = $('.typeahead');
$input.typeahead({
   minLength: 2,
   source: $.get("cities.json", function(data){
      $("#choiseCityName").typeahead({ 
          source:data,
          displayText: function (item) {
            return item.name;
          },
          afterSelect: function(item) {
             return weather.showCityWeather($input.val())
          },
          highlighter: function(item, data) {
             return `<div> ${item} <strong>${data.country}</strong></div>`
          }
       });
    },'json')});
```

Comment: тут выбор плагина не поможет, можно и стандартный Jquery IU. Вы собираетесь все эти 12 MB сразу загружать на сайт?

Comment: Как понять сразу? он просто загружается со страницей. Я еще пока не очень разбираюсь в кеше и тд. подскажете что-нибудь?

Comment: тут проблема не в автокомплите, я так понимаю, у вас просто браузер может зависать на доли секунды из за 12 мб.

Comment: @Arsen, он больше зависает при удалении всего из input

Comment: по всей вероятности это от того что работает onchange на инпуте, т.е при любом изменении вызывается обработчик. Можно найти документацию и попробовать сменить onchange на keypress.

Comment: @Arsen Это уже сложно для меня, но я попробую. Просто смотрел, но не нашел. Спасибо!

Comment: Попробуйте использовать стандартный https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/, если проблем не будет, забейте на  typeahead ))

Answer (score 0):

Я бы советовал [typeahead.js](https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/) от создателей Twitter, хорошо настраивается, хотя изначально мне показался сложным, там же php.net его используют.

Comment: У меня он сейчас стоит, и он очень лагает. но версия https://github.com/bassjobsen/Bootstrap-3-Typeahead/blob/master/README.md